# Update Mongoose document fails TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

Not sure if I'm at all doing this the write way, it's the first attempt at writing a document update REST api call.

I want the api call to supply just the fields of the document they want to update, so I was going to check if each field had data and then add it, or ignore if not to avoid fields being nulled.

As you can see I've tried both to check if the field was not undefined, or the field exists, they both lead to the same server error.

```
app.put('/api/objects/update/:_id', function(req, res)
{
    var id = req.params._id
    var object;

    if (typeof req.body.geometry.coordinates !== undefined) { object.geometry.coordinates = req.body.geometry.coordinates; }
    if (req.body.properties.name) { object.properties.name = req.body.properties.name; }


    Object.updateObject(id, object, {}, function(err, object)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            res.json(err);
            console.log("Object Not Found: " + id);
        }

        res.json(object);
        console.log("Updated Object: " + id);
    });
});
```

This is the contents of the req.body that's being submitted:

```
{
  "properties":
  {
    "name": "Ted"
  }
}
```

Server Error calls out the first if statement and fails.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined
    at /opt/bitnami/apps/API/app.js:221:31
```

First question is can I check for an undefined property to skip it?
Should I be doing it this way at all? If anyone has examples of a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showing the `error` because `object.geometry` is not defined. thus it is coming as `undefined`, when you are trying to assign value to `object.geometry.coordinates`.

you need to define `object` and `object.geometry` as an `object({})` Type, only then you will be able to use dot notation (.). Same thing is with `object.properties`, you need to define it as an `object({})` type.

**Replace:**

```
var object;
```

**With:**

```
var object={};
object.geometry={};
object.properties = {};
```

and everything will work fine for you.

**Update:**

`req.body` has no object as `geometry` inside it, thus `req.body.geometry` is `undefined` and that's why it is throwing that error. first you need to check if `req.body.geometry` exists, and then go for `req.body.geometry.coordinates`

use this:

```
if (req.body.geometry && typeof req.body.geometry.coordinates !== undefined){...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying about the structure of the variable, however the error I'm getting is on the former section of the line, the `if (typeof req.body.geometry.coordinates !== undefined)` part. 

This is the body object I'm trying to submit (I'll add this to the original question), I can't restructure this statement as it's external.

`{
  "properties":
  {
   "name": "Ted"
  }
}`

Comment: i see, req.body has no such field as geometry, thus, req.body.geometry is undefined. you need to check if req.body.geometry exists.